# Android Keystore form USB: Keystore was tampered with or password was incorrect

Tags: android, android-studio, usb, keystore

I was trying to publish an update to my app but I keep on getting the error: `Cannot load key store: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect` My keystore was working on another PC, but after moving it to my current PC by USB stick, it has been giving my this error. I am certain that my password is correct. I understand that there are many question about this error, but none of their solutions seem to work.
Thank You for any possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never ended up finding out what my old keystore password was, but using the keystore brute force attack ([from here](http://maxcamillo.github.io/android-keystore-password-recover/)). I was able to use my key alias password as the keystore password and generate a recovered version of the keystore. All is good now and I hope this solved anyone's problem.